# typescript one line conditonal statement is not working

Tags: typescript

I am getting a number as string. Now i want to check if the string value is integer type or not. So i have written this line of code :

```
const isDotOrComma = this.strValue.indexOf('.') || this.strValue.indexOf(',');
if (isDotOrComma === -1 ) {
   intType = this.strValue;
}
```

So with the above code i am trying to check these string `"123,34" or "123.34" , "12334"`, whether they are integer or not.

Unfortunately, the above code is checking the dots. In case of comma its not working. What wrong have i done ? how can i fix this issue? is there any better way to do this?

May be the above code is working with JavaScript. But with typescript it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator will return the first value that is not undefined, which is -1 in this case, because you are checking the dot first. I would use the `includes` method instead of the `indexOf` method.

```
 const isDotOrComma = this.strValue.includes('.') || this.strValue.includes(',');
 if (!isDotOrComma) {
   intType = this.strValue;
 }
```

Comment: thank you for such wise answer. accepted and up voted.

Comment: As i want to store the integer. if statement should be with  ` if ! (isDotOrComma) `. so if the number has dots of comma then its not integer. Could you please edit your answer @robert-koss